# Dictionary or list in c#

Tags: c#, math, dictionary

I got a strange C# programming problem. There is a data retrieval in groups of random lengths of number groups. The numbers should be all unique, like:

```
group[1]{1,2,15};
group[2]{3,4,7,33,22,100};
group[3]{11,12,9};

// Now there is a routine that adds a number to a group.
// For the example, just imagine the active group looks like:
// group[active]=(10,5,0)
group[active].add(new_number);

// Now if 100 were to be added to the active group
// then the active group should be merged to group[2]
// (as that one already contained 100)
// And then as a result it would like

group[1]{1,2,15};
group[2]{3,4,7,33,22,100,10,5,0};  // 10 5 0 added to group[2]
group[3]{11,12,9};

// 100 wasn't added to group[2] since it was already in there.
```

If the number to be added is already used (not unique) in a previous group.

Then I should merge all numbers in the active group towards that previous group, so I don’t get double numbers.

So in the above example if number 100 was added to the active
group, then all numbers in the `group[active]` should be merged into `group[2]`.

And then the `group[active]` should start clean fresh again without any items. And since 100 was already in `group[2]` it should not be added double.

I am not entirely sure on how to deal with this in a proper way.

As an important criteria here is that it has to work fast.
I will have around minimal 30 groups (upper-bound unknown might be 2000 or more), and their length on average contains five integer numbers, but it could be much longer or only one number.

**I kind of feel that I am reinventing the wheel here.**

- I wonder what this problem is called (does it go by a name, some sorting, or grouping math problem)?, with a name I might find some articles related to such problems.
- But maybe it’s indeed something new, then what would be recommended? Should I use list of lists or a dictionary of lists.. or something else? Somehow the checking if the number is already present should be done fast.

I'm thinking along this path now and am not sure if it’s the best.

Instead of a single number, I use a struct now. It wasn't written in the original question as I was afraid, explaining that would make it too complex.

```
struct data{int ID; int additionalNumber}

Dictionary <int,List<data>> group =new Dictionary<int, List<data>>();
```

I can step aside from using a struct in here. A lookup list could connect the other data to the proper index. So this makes it again more close to the original description.

On a side note, great answers are given.

So far I don’t know yet what would work best for me in my situation.

**Note on the selected answer**

Several answers were given here, but I went for the pure dictionary solution.

Just as a note for people in similar problem scenarios: I'd still recommend testing, and maybe the others work better for you. It’s just that in my case currently it worked best. The code was also quite short which I liked, and a dictionary adds also other handy options for my future coding on this.

Comment: The collection type you might be looking for is [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx). Sets in general don't allow duplicates, so the adding doubles issue is handled by default.

Comment: This question is unclear.  You add a 'new' number to the 'group' and if that number already exists ANYWHERE, you merge the 'group' that contains the 'new' number with the 'active' group?  This is a simple trie/dict/linked-list kinda problem.  Performance in C# with this size data-set should not be an issue (2000 * 5 = 10,000 ... not that big an array in C#!)

Comment: You need to be able to know two pieces of information quickly:  Does a given number already exist?  And 2) In which subgroup is it in?  That matches the criteria of a Dictionary with key value.  The groups themselves can be HashSets.

Comment: i updated the question, since i cannt write in code in the comments.

Comment: @user3800527 How will you get the data? Also seeing your edit, per group, there is a struct of 2 numbers instead of the 1 above in your question?

Comment: I totally didn't understand the question. Based on the sample inputs you've provided, what is the expected output? Maybe that'll help me to understand where your problem is...

Comment: @Alexander Derck the first number is used to work on its a local index number the additionalnumber is not used for sorting this. In simple terms if i had numbred bags they had all unique ID's id's, but their content is not important now, i need to group bags by customer age.
later i do something with the content,  this is the kind of problem area. bags are just an example here, as to explain the problem area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather you want to iteratively assign numbers to groups satisfying these conditions:

1. Each number can be contained in only one of the groups
2. Groups are sets (numbers can occur only once in given group)
3. If number `n` exists in group `g` and we try to add it to group `g'`, all numbers from `g'` should be transferred to `g` instead (avoiding repetitions in `g`)

Although approaches utilizing `Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>` are correct, here's another one (more mathematically based).

You could simply maintain a `Dictionary<int, int>`, in which the key would be the number, and the corresponding value would indicate the group, to which that number belongs (this stems from condition 1.). And here's the add routine:

```
//let's assume dict is a reference to the dictionary
//k is a number, and g is a group
void AddNumber(int k, int g)
{
    //if k already has assigned a group, we assign all numbers from g
    //to k's group (which should be O(n))
    if(dict.ContainsKey(k) && dict[k] != g)
    {
        foreach(var keyValuePair in dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == g).ToList())
            dict[keyValuePair.Key] = dict[k];
    }
    //otherwise simply assign number k to group g (which should be O(1))
    else
    {
        dict[k] = g;
    }
}
```

Notice that from a mathematical point of view what you want to model is a function from a set of numbers to a set of groups.

Comment: Wow this seams also like it, i'm not realy sure of the speed, because i dont know whats faster hashtable or dictionary. From what i red today that Microsoft advice's these days to use dictionaries for speed.
And indeed your right this is a sets and grouping problem. I remind as my math teacher once explained it as writing numbers on paper and draw circles around it to make collections. My rule for that would be like Add to collection unless number is allready in another collection then move entire current content to that collection.

Comment: Your best bet is to create a benchmark which will measure the performance of all proposed solutions. I've written a simple console app that measured adding 1000000 random numbers into 1000 groups - I don't want to brag, but my solution (@17.2225s) proved to be roughly twice as fast as solution using a dictionary of hashsets (@30.8838s) (the latter was based on the solution proposed by @Selman22). Note though, that results may differ in different environments, so it's best if you benchmark them yourself.

Comment: This is the best solution.  It is contrary to the way the question was framed so it takes a sec to sink in.

Comment: @Grx70
As for the moment i go for this solution, it works fast.
And as pure dictionary allow me to do some other things as well 
the other 2 solution are not bad either, and i might try to parallelise one of them later (when i got more time), but i'm not sure if then those will be faster since i think dictionary is allready multicore aware and is therefore so fast in later .net versions.

Answer (score 5):

I would go with `Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>`, since you want to avoid duplicates and want a fast way to check if given number already exists:

Usage example:

```
var groups = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<int>>();

// populate the groups
groups[1] = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1,2,15 });
groups[2] = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 3,4,7,33,22,100 });

int number = 5;
int groupId = 4;

bool numberExists = groups.Values.Any(x => x.Contains(number));

// if there is already a group that contains the number
// merge it with the current group and add the new number
if (numberExists)
{
     var group = groups.First(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(number));
     groups[group.Key].UnionWith(groups[groupId]);
     groups[groupId] = new HashSet<int>();
}
// otherwise just add the new number
else
{
    groups[groupId].Add(number);
}
```

Comment: Trying to grasp my mind around it. My active group is always a new group (can have the highest id) so i never have a similar group[id's]. The problem is that if the active group lets call it `group[active]` is about to get another number added to it, then before adding that number all previous `groups[from id=0 to id=active -1]` should be checked to see if they contain that number. If so the whole active group content should be merged to that previous group (in math terms; the active group is then part of a previous set)

Comment: @user3800527 then we can remove the code that checks if the group exists. the code `groups.Values.Any(x => x.Contains(number));` does the "if the active group lets call it group[active] is about to get another number added to it, then before adding that number all previous groups[from id=0 to id=active -1] should be checked to see if they contain that number." and the commented if statement does the merging.

Comment: Upon merging two groups instead of creating a new hashset with `new HashSet<int>(groups[group.Key].Concat(groups[groupId]))` you could utilize the [`UnionWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342097(v=vs.110).aspx) method: `groups[group.Key].UnionWith(groups[groupId])`. There might be sllight performance boost right there, although I'm not sure of that.

Comment: While benchmarking the code I've come across one major issue with your code - upon calling `.Concat(groups[groupId])` we have no guarantee that `groupId` key is present in the dictionary, so it may lead to a `KeyNotFoundException`. Also, `groups[group.Key].Add(number)` is reduntant, since `group` is the first set that CONTAINS that number.

Comment: @Grx70 I improved the code according to your suggestion. for the key, I'm still not sure where the group comes from, since OP said every group is a new group I guess he can just add the group to dictionary before doing anything. I included a check before but removed it after the OPs comment

Comment: @Selman22 You should remove the assignment - `UnionWith` "returns" `void`.

Answer (score 2):

I have kept it as easy to follow as I can, trying not to impact the speed or deviate from the spec.

[image]

Create a class called Groups.cs and copy and paste this code into it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XXXNAMESPACEXXX
{
    public static class Groups
    {
        public static List<List<int>> group { get; set; }

        public static int active { get; set; }


        public static void AddNumberToGroup(int numberToAdd, int groupToAddItTo)
        {
            try
            {
                if (group == null)
                {
                    group = new List<List<int>>();

                }

                while (group.Count < groupToAddItTo)
                {
                    group.Add(new List<int>());

                }

                int IndexOfListToRefresh = -1;

                List<int> NumbersToMove = new List<int>();

                foreach (List<int> Numbers in group)
                {
                    if (Numbers.Contains(numberToAdd) && (group.IndexOf(Numbers) + 1) != groupToAddItTo)
                    {
                        active = group.IndexOf(Numbers) + 1;

                        IndexOfListToRefresh = group.IndexOf(Numbers);

                        foreach (int Number in Numbers)
                        {
                            NumbersToMove.Add(Number);

                        }

                    }

                }

                foreach (int Number in NumbersToMove)
                {
                    if (!group[groupToAddItTo - 1].Contains(Number))
                    {
                        group[groupToAddItTo - 1].Add(Number);

                    }

                }

                if (!group[groupToAddItTo - 1].Contains(numberToAdd))
                {
                    group[groupToAddItTo - 1].Add(numberToAdd);

                }

                if (IndexOfListToRefresh != -1)
                {
                    group[IndexOfListToRefresh] = new List<int>();

                }

            }
            catch//(Exception ex)
            {
                //Exception handling here
            }
        }

        public static string GetString()
        {
            string MethodResult = "";
            try
            {
                string Working = "";

                bool FirstPass = true;

                foreach (List<int> Numbers in group)
                {
                    if (!FirstPass)
                    {
                        Working += "\r\n";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FirstPass = false;

                    }

                    Working += "group[" + (group.IndexOf(Numbers) + 1) + "]{";

                    bool InnerFirstPass = true;

                    foreach (int Number in Numbers)
                    {
                        if (!InnerFirstPass)
                        {
                            Working += ", ";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            InnerFirstPass = false;

                        }

                        Working += Number.ToString();

                    }

                    Working += "};";

                    if ((active - 1) == group.IndexOf(Numbers))
                    {
                        Working += " //<active>";

                    }

                }

                MethodResult = Working;

            }
            catch//(Exception ex)
            {
                //Exception handling here
            }
            return MethodResult;
        }


    }

}
```

I don't know if foreach is more or less efficient than standard for loops, so I have made an alternative version that uses standard for loops:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XXXNAMESPACEXXX
{
    public static class Groups
    {
        public static List<List<int>> group { get; set; }

        public static int active { get; set; }


        public static void AddNumberToGroup(int numberToAdd, int groupToAddItTo)
        {
            try
            {
                if (group == null)
                {
                    group = new List<List<int>>();

                }

                while (group.Count < groupToAddItTo)
                {
                    group.Add(new List<int>());

                }

                int IndexOfListToRefresh = -1;

                List<int> NumbersToMove = new List<int>();

                for(int i = 0; i < group.Count; i++)
                {
                    List<int> Numbers = group[i];

                    int IndexOfNumbers = group.IndexOf(Numbers) + 1;

                    if (Numbers.Contains(numberToAdd) && IndexOfNumbers != groupToAddItTo)
                    {
                        active = IndexOfNumbers;

                        IndexOfListToRefresh = IndexOfNumbers - 1;

                        for (int j = 0; j < Numbers.Count; j++)
                        {
                            int Number = NumbersToMove[j];

                            NumbersToMove.Add(Number);

                        }

                    }

                }

                for(int i = 0; i < NumbersToMove.Count; i++)
                {
                    int Number = NumbersToMove[i];

                    if (!group[groupToAddItTo - 1].Contains(Number))
                    {
                        group[groupToAddItTo - 1].Add(Number);

                    }

                }

                if (!group[groupToAddItTo - 1].Contains(numberToAdd))
                {
                    group[groupToAddItTo - 1].Add(numberToAdd);

                }

                if (IndexOfListToRefresh != -1)
                {
                    group[IndexOfListToRefresh] = new List<int>();

                }

            }
            catch//(Exception ex)
            {
                //Exception handling here
            }
        }

        public static string GetString()
        {
            string MethodResult = "";
            try
            {
                string Working = "";

                bool FirstPass = true;

                for(int i = 0; i < group.Count; i++)
                {
                    List<int> Numbers = group[i];

                    if (!FirstPass)
                    {
                        Working += "\r\n";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FirstPass = false;

                    }

                    Working += "group[" + (group.IndexOf(Numbers) + 1) + "]{";

                    bool InnerFirstPass = true;

                    for(int j = 0; j < Numbers.Count; j++)
                    {
                        int Number = Numbers[j];

                        if (!InnerFirstPass)
                        {
                            Working += ", ";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            InnerFirstPass = false;

                        }

                        Working += Number.ToString();

                    }

                    Working += "};";

                    if ((active - 1) == group.IndexOf(Numbers))
                    {
                        Working += " //<active>";

                    }

                }

                MethodResult = Working;

            }
            catch//(Exception ex)
            {
                //Exception handling here
            }
            return MethodResult;
        }


    }

}
```

Both implimentations contain the group variable and two methods, which are; AddNumberToGroup and GetString, where GetString is used to check the current status of the group variable.

***Note: You'll need to replace XXXNAMESPACEXXX with the Namespace of your project. Hint: Take this from another class.***

When adding an item to your List, do this:

```
int NumberToAdd = 10;

int GroupToAddItTo = 2;

AddNumberToGroup(NumberToAdd, GroupToAddItTo);
```

...or...

```
AddNumberToGroup(10, 2);
```

In the example above, I am adding the number 10 to group 2.

Test the speed with the following:

```
DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;

int NumberOfTimesToRepeatTest = 1000;

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfTimesToRepeatTest; i++)
{
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(4, 1);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(3, 1);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(8, 2);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(5, 2);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(7, 3);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(3, 3);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(8, 4);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(43, 4);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(100, 5);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(1, 5);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(5, 6);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(78, 6);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(34, 7);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(456, 7);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(456, 8);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(7, 8);
    Groups.AddNumberToGroup(7, 9);

}

long MillisecondsTaken = DateTime.Now.Ticks - StartTime.Ticks;

Console.WriteLine(Groups.GetString());

Console.WriteLine("Process took: " + MillisecondsTaken);
```

I think this is what you need. Let me know if I misunderstood anything in the question.

As far as I can tell it's brilliant, it's fast and it's tested.

Enjoy!

...and one more thing:

For the little windows interface app, I just created a simple winforms app with three textboxes (one set to multiline) and a button.

Then, after adding the Groups class above, in the button-click event I wrote the following:

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int Group = int.Parse(TxtGroup.Text);

        int Number = int.Parse(TxtNumber.Text);

        Groups.AddNumberToGroup(Number, Group);

        TxtOutput.Text = Groups.GetString();

    }
    catch//(Exception ex)
    {
        //Exception handling here
    }
}
```

Comment: Also a good example (thanks)... this time using list of lists.
i'm not yet sure what is best (list of lists, dictionairy with hashtable, or pure dictionairy based. I have to think it over all those answers, speed is a major concern to me.  ..

Comment: Allready 73 for normal situations thats pretty fast, but my situation is not so normal. I think i will just need to check the 3 answers, at my pc at at work.(im at home now) the machine at work is a octocore with 32GB ram 3.4Ghz
Though maybe your example could be parallelized in execution. To faster check for existing. As i think there is the major ticks eater.

Comment: Absolutely right. It's best to check as many different ways as possible. I'm realy enjoying this project. I knew speed is a major issue for you, and because of that I added speed tests above. This can be applied to all other implementations too.

Comment: Hmm, it's going to be tricky to spread the operation over eight cores. Would be preferable to have a processor that's eight times faster instead of eight simultaneous cores. At least you can run eight of them at once, or have seven other processes running at the same time as this one.

Comment: well development goes on, i use for the moment the solution of GRx70, but i'll keep a hyperlink to your solution because I might want to parallelise this in the future and then use something based on this. If i had more time i would dive into your code deeper to try this. but I'm not sure if would succeed and then next if it would indeed be faster (given that i think that dictionary objects are already optimized for speed. And they allow us some more things.